# Should I use the static reference from the main module or directly refer to the singleton classes?

Tags: java, static, singleton

Ok I will try to build a short framework for discussing about, `Engine` and `Physics` are both singleton:

```
public enum Engine {
    INSTANCE();
    public static final Physics PHYSICS = Physics.INSTANCE;
    // following some private variables for the Engine instance..
    private Engine() {
        //ctor
    }
}
```

Objects in the framework refer to the engine like so:

```
public class Object {
    public static final Engine ENGINE = Engine.INSTANCE;
```

This might be a method from an Object instance in the framework:

```
    public void register() {
        ENGINE.register(this);
        // Now the first (1) alternative from the alternatives below:
        Engine.PHYSICS.update();
    }
```

As every Entity in the Engine derives from `Object`, all of the objects share the Engine reference with the same static variable. So far so good (or not good? ).
Now regarding my title question there are different alternatives on how objects can refer to modules of the engine:

**(1)** Objects in the framework refer to other modules of the engine by the static variables provided in the Engine (e.g. use `Engine.PHYSICS`)

**(2)** or they call the instance method using `Physics.INSTANCE`.

**(3)** or another alternative would be, that Engine holds a non static variable (e.g. `public final Physics physics = Physics.INSTANCE`) and objects would refer to the Physics module like so: `ENGINE.physics`

I have to admit I am a bit confused on how using singletons and static references efficiently together. The one thing I know: I always want the client to use the same Engine and Physics instances for one session.

Comment: Generally, the static reference is private in a singleton, and so we access it through the  `Singleton.getInstance()` method from anywhere.

Comment: Would it be wiser (more beautiful) if the Engine singleton would be the only singleton in the framework, itself creating static instances of a non-singleton Phyiscs class? So Objects in the framework would be forced to use any modules by referring to the `Engine` singleton?

Comment: From my very personal point of view, `Engine` should instantiate the `Physics` class in a non-static way. Then, you will access to the module with `Engine.getInstance().getPhysics()`

Comment: The only flaw I see: It could happen that I accidentally instantiate a new Physics object in a package member. Resulting that the Physics being used then, would be a totally different instance than the one I should use (being `Engine.INSTANCE.physics`)

Comment: You're right, but I don't see how you can 'accidentally' instantiate a new Physics object ^^ You maybe can create a specific package for your engine and module, and set the constructor as package friendly (the default access modifier) or protected. In this way, you can't create a `Physics` object in another package